# Html Text highlight problem in flutter. Can I highlight html text in flutter?

Tags: html, database, flutter, highlight

I want to highlight html text and want to save highlighted portion in database . But,I can't find any library or any logic to do that.Can I do the job by flutter?
N.B: I had done this functionality by android native system.Can I do it in flutter?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have actually done it android but not in flutter.I am new in flutter. I haven't got any clue to highlight html text in flutter. Is it possible to highlight html text in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

To display HTML you can try  [css_text](https://pub.dev/packages/css_text) package. Using above package's `HTML.toTextSpan` mehtod you can convert HTML into `TextSpan` object. Then pass that to a [SelectableText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html) Widget Using the `SelectableText.rich` constructor.